# Stale InfoPath form cache

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a InfoPath template that submits it's forms to a SharePoint server.  If the user improperly closes InfoPath the write lock for the form he has open is not removed on the server.  When the form is re-opened the user gets an error stating that someone has the form open.  This is all standard stuff and the lock usually clears itself after 10 minutes.

But sometimes the error message never clears on the original users computer.  The write lock on the server clears normally, anyone else can access the file just fine.  But the original computer never allows write access to the file again.  We can wait days and it still doesn't clear.  Looks like that computer keeps the write lock in it's cache somewhere and never bothers to check the server again.  Is there any method I can use to clear this cache or force the computer out of this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is the Internet Explorer cache.  Clearing the temporary internet files solves this problem.